# Add weight to a relationship using neo4j embedded java api

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-embedded

I would like to add a weight to a relationship using Embedded Neo4j Java API.

For example : `A` knows `B` very well so their relationship should be weighted `5`. On the other hand, `A` knows `C` very little so their relationship should be weighted `1`.

How can I do that?

PS : I have already tried the example here : http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-graph-algo.html but it doesn't recognize th functions `createNode( "name", "A", "x", 0d, "y", 0d )` and `createRelationship( nodeA, nodeC, "length", 2d )`.

This is the code :

```
package com.neo4j.test.test1;

import org.neo4j.graphalgo.CommonEvaluators;
import org.neo4j.graphalgo.EstimateEvaluator;
import org.neo4j.graphalgo.GraphAlgoFactory;
import org.neo4j.graphalgo.PathFinder;
import org.neo4j.graphalgo.WeightedPath;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.PathExpanders;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;

import com.neo4j.test.labels.NodeLabels;
import com.neo4j.test.labels.TypeRelation;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
        GraphDatabaseService db = dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase("C:\\Zakaria\\NeoTests\\Test2");

        try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {

            Node nodeA = createNode( "name", "A", "x", 0d, "y", 0d );
            Node nodeB = createNode( "name", "B", "x", 7d, "y", 0d );
            Node nodeC = createNode( "name", "C", "x", 2d, "y", 1d );
            Relationship relAB = createRelationship( nodeA, nodeC, "length", 2d );
            Relationship relBC = createRelationship( nodeC, nodeB, "length", 3d );
            Relationship relAC = createRelationship( nodeA, nodeB, "length", 10d );

            EstimateEvaluator<Double> estimateEvaluator = new EstimateEvaluator<Double>()
            {
                @Override
                public Double getCost( final Node node, final Node goal )
                {
                    double dx = (Double) node.getProperty( "x" ) - (Double) goal.getProperty( "x" );
                    double dy = (Double) node.getProperty( "y" ) - (Double) goal.getProperty( "y" );
                    double result = Math.sqrt( Math.pow( dx, 2 ) + Math.pow( dy, 2 ) );
                    return result;
                }
            };
            PathFinder<WeightedPath> astar = GraphAlgoFactory.aStar(
                    PathExpanders.allTypesAndDirections(),
                    CommonEvaluators.doubleCostEvaluator( "length" ), estimateEvaluator );
            WeightedPath path = astar.findSinglePath( nodeA, nodeB );

            tx.success();

        }

        System.out.println("Done!");

    }

}
```

It should give this result :

[image]

It says that these following functions are not defined :

```
Node nodeA = createNode( "name", "A", "x", 0d, "y", 0d );
Node nodeB = createNode( "name", "B", "x", 7d, "y", 0d );
Node nodeC = createNode( "name", "C", "x", 2d, "y", 1d );
Relationship relAB = createRelationship( nodeA, nodeC, "length", 2d );
Relationship relBC = createRelationship( nodeC, nodeB, "length", 3d );
Relationship relAC = createRelationship( nodeA, nodeB, "length", 10d );
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code you have tried, as well as any error messages it produces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said Ryan, Java compiler doesn't detect the methods `createNode()` and `createRelationship()` that you use.

This is a way to create the Nodes, and works for me:

```
try (Transaction Tx = gdbs.beginTx(){
    Node nodo = gdbs.createNode();
    nodo.addLabel(p);   // if you have Labels
    nodo.setProperty("property1", someValue);
    Tx.success();
    Tx.close();
} catch (Exception e){//do something}
```

For relationships, only show you how to add properties:

```
relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo(secondNode, RelTypes.KNOWS );
relationship.setProperty( "message", "brave Neo4j " );
```

Depending of your Neo4j version, you should see how create Nodes and Relationships. Last, I have you create nodes and relationships, and without commit them, you create the PathFinder. I recommend you persist the nodes before querying the graph as good practice.

Answer (score 0):

These methods aren't defined as methods in class `Test1`, but rather on `GraphDatabaseService`.  So, you need to do `db.createNode()` and `db.createRelationship()`.  That should work for you.

Comment: Can you define how it didn't work?  What was the specific error?

Comment: It is just as you said, `These methods aren't defined as methods in class Test1`

Comment: sorry, I meant: what is the error you get when you try db.createNode()  and db.createRelationship.  The methods are defined in anything implementing the GraphDatabaseService interface: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html

Answer (score 0):

The methods createNode() and createRelationship() are not defined in neo4j java API as you are using these.